# Create a model of background from multiple images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, background

I am trying to create a model of background from multiple images of the same size. I want to use the model to segment moving objects from the roller belt (background model), but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

My concern is how to compute background model with 4 images representing roller belt?

I was thinking of calculating mean for each belt image, add it together, and divide it by the number of images, but in this case I will end up with one value for the whole background. How can I compute the mean of each pixel by looking at 4 images provided?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. You want to average over all 4 images? Thus the first pixel of the resulting image contains the average of all first pixels of each image etc...

Comment: precisely, this is what I am trying to achieve

Comment: You greatly increase the chances of getting answers if you add a sample image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%some example data
A{1}=imread('http://dummyimage.com/600x400/00a/fff.jpg&text=a');
A{2}=imread('http://dummyimage.com/600x400/00a/fff.jpg&text=b');
A{3}=imread('http://dummyimage.com/600x400/00a/fff.jpg&text=c');
A{4}=imread('http://dummyimage.com/600x400/00a/fff.jpg&text=d');

%make sure every image is of type double. Every uint type is possible as well, but requires casting at the end.
for ix=1:numel(A),A{ix}=im2double(A{ix});end


%concatinate on ndims+1, which means 4th dimension for color images and third dimension for grey scale images.    
I=mean(cat(ndims(A{1})+1,A{:}),ndims(A{1})+1);
imshow(I);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the images are im1,im2,im3,im4 calculate the mean along the third dimension.

```
% concatenate the images to a single 3-D stack.
im = cat(3,im1,im2,im3,im4);

% find the mean of each pixel.
meanIm = mean(im,3);
```

Comment: This code can only deal with greyscale images of type double.